# How to retrieve the status of a stripe subscription USING PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have successfully created checkout sessions and webhooks. Now I have stored $SubscriptionID and want to check the status of my subscription with Stripe.

Instructions on Stripe website (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve)
say to use

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($secretKey);
$stripe->subscriptions->retrieve($SubscriptionID, []);
```

This yields this array:

```
Stripe\StripeClient Object
(
    [coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient:private] => Stripe\Service\CoreServiceFactory Object
        (
            [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
            [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                (
                    [subscriptions] => Stripe\Service\SubscriptionService Object
                        (
                            [client:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                            [streamingClient:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                        )

                )

        )

    [config:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Array
        (
            [api_key] => (key)
            [client_id] => 
            [stripe_account] => 
            [stripe_version] => 2023-08-16
            [api_base] => https://api.stripe.com
            [connect_base] => https://connect.stripe.com
            [files_base] => https://files.stripe.com
        )

    [defaultOpts:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
        (
            [apiKey] => 
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [Stripe-Account] => 
                    [Stripe-Version] => 2023-08-16
                )

            [apiBase] => 
        )

    [preview] => Stripe\Preview Object
        (
            [client:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
        )

)
```

which does not at all look like expected response (which should have status) according to stripe website, namely:

```
{
  "id": "sub_1MowQVLkdIwHu7ixeRlqHVzs",
  "object": "subscription",
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "billing_cycle_anchor": 1679609767,
  "billing_thresholds": null,
  "cancel_at": null,
  "cancel_at_period_end": false,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_details": {
    "comment": null,
    "feedback": null,
    "reason": null
  },
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1679609767,
  "currency": "usd",
  "current_period_end": 1682288167,
  "current_period_start": 1679609767,
  "customer": "cus_Na6dX7aXxi11N4",
  "days_until_due": null,
  "default_payment_method": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "default_tax_rates": [],
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "items": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "si_Na6dzxczY5fwHx",
        "object": "subscription_item",
        "billing_thresholds": null,
        "created": 1679609768,
        "metadata": {},
        "plan": {
          "id": "price_1MowQULkdIwHu7ixraBm864M",
          "object": "plan",
          "active": true,
          "aggregate_usage": null,
          "amount": 1000,
          "amount_decimal": "1000",
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1679609766,
          "currency": "usd",
          "interval": "month",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_Na6dGcTsmU0I4R",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed"
        },
        "price": {
          "id": "price_1MowQULkdIwHu7ixraBm864M",
          "object": "price",
          "active": true,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1679609766,
          "currency": "usd",
          "custom_unit_amount": null,
          "livemode": false,
          "lookup_key": null,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_Na6dGcTsmU0I4R",
          "recurring": {
            "aggregate_usage": null,
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed"
          },
          "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_quantity": null,
          "type": "recurring",
          "unit_amount": 1000,
          "unit_amount_decimal": "1000"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_1MowQVLkdIwHu7ixeRlqHVzs",
        "tax_rates": []
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_1MowQVLkdIwHu7ixeRlqHVzs"
  },
  "latest_invoice": "in_1MowQWLkdIwHu7ixuzkSPfKd",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "pause_collection": null,
  "payment_settings": {
    "payment_method_options": null,
    "payment_method_types": null,
    "save_default_payment_method": "off"
  },
  "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
  "pending_setup_intent": null,
  "pending_update": null,
  "quantity": 1,
  "schedule": null,
  "start_date": 1679609767,
  "status": "active",
  "test_clock": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "trial_end": null,
  "trial_settings": {
    "end_behavior": {
      "missing_payment_method": "create_invoice"
    }
  },
  "trial_start": null
}
```

What am I doing wrong? TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

the call `$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($secretKey);` creates a Stripe client. This lets you access all the API methods. It doesn't store any information about the responses to various API requests.

What you need to store is store the returned value of each call. For example you want this:

```
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->retrieve($SubscriptionID, []);
```

This will give you a $subscription variable that has all the properties of a Subscription [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object). So you can do `$subscription->id` or `$subscription->status` after that.